# Getting 12V out of 60V battery bank

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I have a 60V battery bank with 16 Li-ion cells in series. I was wondering if I could get 12V output by connecting a wire across 3 or 4 cells in series and using it to control the 12V dc fan of the battery box.

Comment: Unbalanced loading of series cells is seldom a good idea. If your BMS can rebalance all cells when charging it may be viable. As others npte, avoid deep discharge - even if the batteries include that in their spec. | Many buck converters on ebay at lower than parts cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely not a good idea as you would not have equal discharge from all cells in the bank.  This could (depending on how sophisticated and complex your charger is) cause trouble with charging.  It could also cause shortened pack run time and reduced pack life.  Depending on how the pack is constructed it could also impact some of the safety features.

You're better off with a buck converter that will take the 60V and convert it down to 12V.

Comment: I am using an MPPT (connected to solar array) for charging purposes and the battery has a BMS system attached to it. I needed the 12V for controlling relays and ither small instruments.